# How can I use Logback to log to 2 different files in the same class?

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

Our Java application uses SLF4J on top of Logback to log error messages.  In our logback.xml, we have an `appender` defined for the error log, along with a `logger` that specifies the top level of our package hierarchy.

We are adding functionality to log data to a different log file.  I created a class to handle this logging, and I added a new `appender` to the logback.xml as well as a new `logger`.  The new `logger` specifies the fully qualified package name of the new class that I created (along with `additivity="false"`), so that only that specific class will write to the new log file when it invokes the SLF4J logger.

Then I realized that if the new class fails to write to the new log file for whatever reason, I should have it log an error message to our original error log file.  But how can that class write to the original error log file, when its SLF4J logger writes to the new log file?  Is there a way for that class to get a handle to a logger to the original error log file?

Answer (score -1):

It might be easiest to make the new class have two loggers: one would be it's own's and the other would be the logger used to log errors. It's not forbidden for a class to use two loggers simultaniously (but for different purposes):

```
public class NewClass {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NewClass.class);
    private static final Logger errorLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorHandlingClass.class);

    public void respond() {
        logger.info("info file");
        try {
            doSomething();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorLogger.error("error doing something", e);
        }
    }
```

*However*, if you write to the "new log file" using SLF4J logger, I don't think you can detect that writing failed.